# How to Download Data in Android using completion handler?

Tags: android, json

My background is from iOS. 
I use AFNetworking to download data. I make completion handler to let me know as downloading finishes. The completion handler returns me NSData, which I subsequently parse.

I keep all stuff of downloading into a separate class. I simply pass URL, parameters and it downloads and returns me data.

How can I achieve such strategy in Android.

MY STUDY:

I read from

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#http-client

where I found that I do it inside Activity, If I use it in a separate class. it creates issue of context and other stuff.

When I read in detail whole document, I found that I can put stuff in other class, but I can't find any COMPLETION HANDLER, to sent data back to Activity class.

**So, Major portion of my class, how to download using COMPLETION HANDLER.**

Thanks.

Comment: There are really nice libraries you can try which make your life really easy, such as Volley or Retrofit...give those a try, first.

Comment: I saw Retrofit, but issue is that how can I centralized all downloading methods and let my activity know that data is downloaded.  No concept of completion handler.

Comment: They use          Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
                        .build();     So, how can I sent data which comes from this URL, or any data, which this library gives me back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In case you'd like to try Retrofit, [here are some good examples to get started with](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit) and answering your question, they do have a callback for when your data is downloaded:

   ```
   User user = new User(123, "John Doe");
   Call<User> call = apiService.createuser(user);
   call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Response<User> response,
         Retrofit retrofit) {
           // THIS is where you get a successful callback when your data is downloaded
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
           // Callback for error cases
       }
   ```
2. If you'd prefer volley, [here is their documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#simple) and an example on how to do a basic network call with callbacks:

   ```
   // Instantiate the RequestQueue. 
   RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
   String url ="http://www.google.com";

   // Request a string response from the provided URL. 
   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
           new Response.Listener<String>() {
       @Override 
       public void onResponse(String response) {
           // THIS is the successful callback
       } 
   }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override 
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           // Error callback
       } 
   }); 
   // Add the request to the RequestQueue. 
   queue.add(stringRequest);
   ```

Comment: I read this whole tutorial, still accepting as its relevant answer :)